# Selecting specific rows based on conditions in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is a small snapshot of data from which I need to extract information.

```
ID      FREQ      LTD          SD           LWD     DPD
_______________________________________________________
1021    Weekly  2016-05-27  2016-05-23  2016-05-31  0
1021    Weekly  2016-05-27  2016-05-27  2016-05-31  0
1021    Weekly  2016-06-02  2016-06-06  2016-06-30  24
1021    Weekly  2016-06-02  2016-06-13  2016-06-30  17
1021    Weekly  2016-06-02  2016-06-20  2016-06-30  10
1021    Weekly  2016-06-02  2016-06-27  2016-06-30  0
1021    Weekly  2017-02-27  2017-02-06  2017-02-28  0
1021    Weekly  2017-02-27  2017-02-13  2017-02-28  0
```

LTD = Last Transaction Date of that month

SD = Scheduled Dates of that month when the payment was supposed to come.

LWD = Last Working Day of that month.

DPD = Days Past Due which is calculated as 
`when freq = 'Weekly' and SD between LTD and LWD AND datediff(LWD, SD) > 7 THEN datediff(LWD, SD) as DPD`. All the Dates are of Date Datatype.

Now, see the sample data and notice the 6th and the 7th row. The 7th row calculates the DPD as 0 taking in account the `LWD` and 'SD' of that month. However it should be calculating the DPD taking in account that after `2016-06-02` the next payment came on `2017-02-27` so in DPD calculation, days should be added for the next 6 months in which there was no transaction.

How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated.

My current Query is:

```
select y.*,
      case when freq_term = 'Daily' and scheduled_date between last_transaction_date and last_working_day 
           AND datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) > 1 THEN datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date)
           -- WHEN freq_term = 'Daily' AND datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) > 1 THEN datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) 

           -- when freq_term = 'Weekly' and scheduled_date between last_transaction_date and last_working_day 
           -- AND datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) > 7 THEN datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date)
            WHEN freq_term = 'Weekly' AND datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) > 7 THEN datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date)

           WHEN freq_term = 'Bi-Monthly' AND datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) > 14 THEN datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date)
           WHEN freq_term = 'Monthly' AND datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) > 30 THEN datediff(last_working_day, Scheduled_Date) END 'DPD'
from
(
select id, 
      freq_term,
      max_date 'Last_Transaction_date',
      t3.date 'Scheduled_date',
      date(last_day(date) - (CASE DAYOFWEEK(last_day(date)) WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as 'Last_working_day'
from
  (
    select 
      jlp.id, 
      jlp.freq_term,
      t1.max_date,
      t1month,
      t1year
    from jos_lender_portfolio jlp
    inner join 
      (
        select lpid, year(date) t1year, month(date) t1month, max(date) max_date
        from jos_lender_transactions
        where description in('Payment', 'Partial Payoff', 'Early Payoff') 
        and date <= '2018-01-01'
        group by lpid, year(date),month(date)
      )t1 on jlp.id = t1.lpid
    where id = 1021
    order by 3
  )t
inner join 
  (SELECT 
      lpid, 
      date,
      MONTH(DATE) t3month,
      year(date) t3year  
   from jos_lender_trans_backup where description = 'Payment' and lpid = 1021 order by date
  )t3
on t.id = t3.lpid and t.t1month = t3.t3month and t.t1year = t3.t3year
)y
group by id, last_day(Last_Transaction_date)
order by Scheduled_Date;
```

Comment: which data type are the columns LTD, SD and LWD?? ... and post  your query too

Comment: They are all Dates. And I possted my Query also

Comment: Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!